# Adding records in the GAMS dotnet api have no keys

Tags: c#, math, gams-math, operations-research

When adding records to a set, the resulting `keys` variable contains only one empty string, instead of the expect `"i1"`.

```
var workspace = new GAMSWorkspace("TestWorkspace");
var database = workspace.AddDatabase();
var set = database.AddSet("TestSet", 1);
var record = set.AddRecord("i1");
var keys = record.Keys;
database.Export("TestDb");
```

What can cause this problem running the version `Assembly GAMS.net4, Version=28.2.0.0`

When I export the `database` to a .gdx file, the set contains the element `i1`.

Answer (score 0):

How did you check, that the `keys`variable does not contain the expected string? The `record.Keys` property returns a `string[]`. And if I add a `WriteLine` to your example, I get the expected string:

```
var database = ws.AddDatabase();
var set = database.AddSet("TestSet", 1);
var record = set.AddRecord("i1");
var keys = record.Keys;
Console.WriteLine(keys[0]);
```

Output:

```
i1
```

Comment: I checked it the same way you did. But the output is always `""`. Which api version are you using?

Comment: I used 28.2.0.0 (from C:\GAMS\win64\28.2\GAMS.net4.dll). So I guess, it is the same you used?

Comment: Yes, so I guess I have some problems with my system setup.

Comment: Might be. But it is strange, that things seem to work in general, so that you get the expected element in the set after exporting to GDX. I do not have a good explanation for this at the moment